# enable disable iframe when checked checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, checkbox

this is my code :-

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>(Type a title for your page here)</title>
    <script language="JavaScript">
    <!--

    function enable_text(status)
    {
    status=!status; 
    document.f1.other_text.disabled = status;
    }
    //-->
    </script>
    </head>
    <body onload=enable_text(false);>

    <form name=f1 method=post>
    <input type="checkbox" name="others" onclick="enable_text(this.checked)" >Others
    <iframe name="other_text" src="www.google.com"></iframe>
    </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

right now i am click on check box same its enable 
 not checked check box same enable 
here i want to set if i click on check box then iframe is disable if check out then enable

Comment: so what is happening now?

Comment: And explain yourself properly, when you ask a question .. Try to phrase it better, otherwise it becomes difficult to understand from a 2nd person perspective.

Comment: enable at all time when check box is checked or other

Comment: Disable iframe? What do you mean?

Comment: `iframe`s can't be disabled. Do you want to toggle visibility, or make an iframe look like it was a disabled form, i.e. have grayed content and unresponsive iframe?

Comment: i want inside content of iframe readonly not i frame disable now how its possible

Answer (score 2):

`disabled`, in HTML terms, means "This form control is readonly and cannot be 'successful'" (successful meaning "will appear in submitted data").

`iframe` elements are not form controls, do not accept user input, and are not submitted with form data.

The term `disabled` has no meaning when applied to an iframe, so you cannot do this.

---

Update re comment:

> i want inside content of iframe readonly not i frame disable now how its possible

Regular content inside an iframe, just like regular content anywhere else, **is** readonly.

If you want to disable form controls in a document in an iframe, then navigate through the DOM to those form controls and disable the form controls (subject to the normal cross-domain limitations of JS across frames).

Comment: I don't get your sentence "Regular content... is readonly". Form values and editable elements are regular content the user can interact with (and this is what the OP is referring to with Google).

Answer (score 0):

You can't disable the iframe itself.

A workaround would be to position a transparent div above your iframe, which would prevent the user from interacting with the iframe content. To enable interaction you would just remove the div.